# How to specify the block name in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

This is a basic question, but which drove me sleepless for the past a few days.

I wrote a customized module with a controller, a phtml template and a block class as below:
    app/code/local/Huahan/HelloWorld/Block
        Helloworld.php  (where Huahan_Helloworld_Block_Helloworld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template)
    app/code/local/Huahan/HelloWorld/controllers
        IndexController.php  (where indexAction of index controller is defined)
    app/design/frontend/base/default/template/huahan/helloworld
        helloworld.phtml     (where view is defined)
    app/design/frontend/base/default/layout
        helloworld.xml (the filename "helloworld.xml" is specified in etc/config.xml)

I know that every request handling in Magento starts from a controller and its action method.

In the layout helloworld.xml, I specifies the template file in the block tag

```
<helloworld_index_nihao>
<block type="core/template" name="just_an_arbitary_name" output="toHtml" template="huahan/helloworld/nihao.phtml"/>
</helloworld_index_nihao>
</layout>
```

So the controller knows which template to use while handling request.

**The problem is how I can let Magento know that Huahan_Helloworld_Block_Helloworld is the block class I want it to load before rendering any output?**

And if there is any detailed documentation about the Magento xml? I am always frustrated by the complex and arbitrariness of the Magento xml syntax

The version of Magento is ver.1.9.0.1

The config.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<huahan_helloworld>
<version>
0.1.0
</version>
</huahan_helloworld>
</modules>


<frontend>
<routers>
<!-- the <helloworld> tagname appears to be arbitrary, but by
convention is should match the frontName tag below-->
        <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                        <module>Huahan_HelloWorld</module>
                        <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
        </helloworld>
</routers>

<layout>
        <updates>
                <helloworld>
                        <file>helloworld.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
        </updates>
</layout>
</frontend>

<global>
        <blocks>
                <helloworld>
                        <class>Huahan_Helloworld_block</class>
                </helloworld>
        </blocks>
</global>

</config>
```

Thanks in advance. I really appreciate that you read it down here.

Answer (score 1):

### Block types

The block `type` attribute is the item which configures what class a block uses. Using a full class-name in the `type` although possible is discouraged.

The purpose of the class-alias system in Magento is to allow you the flexibility if extending/overwriting core/module functionality in your own modules.

If everyone uses the class-alias you can then replace/override an alias with your own classes and "inject" your behavior instead of the original. It's a form of decoupling code to allow extendability.

### Block configs

In your module declaration you already had to specify a block prefix such as:

```
<blocks>
    <huahan_helloworld>
        <class>Huahan_Helloworld_Block</class>
    </huahan_helloworld>
</blocks>
```

According to Magento conventions the `<class>` part should be either `huahan_helloworld` or `helloworld`.

Because of these configurations and other Magento conventions your block type should be `huahan_helloworld/helloworld` or `helloworld/helloworld` (respectively).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The layout xml file is where I should work.

Just change the value of type="core/template" in block item of helloworld.xml to type="Huahan_Helloworld_Block_Helloworld"

then it is done!

I hate Magento, "core/template" does not look like a class name from any view angle!

Comment: That should not work. The block type is not a plain string of the block class name, it follows the `group/block_name` structure. I don't know what you've specified as your group name because I can't see your `config.xml` file though.

Comment: @ZeLoubs is correct - depending upon your config.xml file, your type will likely be `huahan_helloworld/helloworld` or perhaps `helloworld/helloworld`.  Paste in your config.xml file and we can give you a more definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have posted the config.xml in the question body. It does work.

Comment: @ZeLoubs AFAIK from Magento internals I've seen code which first checks if there is a `/` in the string and if there isn't it attempts to use the string as a class directly.

Comment: @ZeLoubs so in fact using the class directly would work but it's not advised to do so for multiple reasons.